# How to iterate over dictionary in assemblyscript

Tags: assemblyscript

```
let treasury: Record<string, string> = {};
treasury.firstWallet = "0xEA91B5E687a490380C52d264D5d36558d79F4188".toLowerCase()

for (let wallet in treasury) { ...
```

With this code I am getting the below, with a little red arrow between 'wallet' and 'in', and a '; expected' under 'wallet'

```
Compile subgraphERROR TS1110: Type expected.

   for (let wallet in treasury) {
```

So what's wrong with this and what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssemblyScript doesn't have dynamic objects. But you can use `Map`

```
const treasury: Map<string, string> = new Map()
  .set("firstWallet", "0xea91b5e687a490380c52d264d5d36558d79f4188")
  .set("secondWallet", "0xea91b5e687a490380c52d264d5d36558d79f4188")

const wallets = treasury.values();
for (let i = 0, len = wallets.length; i < len; i++) {
  let wallet = wallets[i];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxGraevy. My VSCode doesn't recognize Map. Do you happen to know what library or version I need in my package.json to make this available?